# dependabot configuration: allow property not allowing updates of dependencies as expected

Tags: yaml, configuration-files, dependabot

I am trying to customize which dependencies are updated using the `allow` property of Dependabot's configuration YAML.

#### Research: `allow`

I see that the [`allow`](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot/dependabot-version-updates/configuration-options-for-the-dependabot.yml-file#allow) property is preventing update of the dependencies instead of allowing update. Also, an allow for one dependency is preventing update for all dependencies.

For example I added the `allow` property as below to **allow for update of just one dependency poi-ooxml**. I want to skip updates to all other dependencies.

```yaml
  allow:
    - dependency-name: "org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml"
```

Result:

- All dependency updates are skipped.

Log file:

```
2022-06-16T20:41:32.4554260Z Checking if org.apache.poi:poi 4.1.1 needs updating
2022-06-16T20:41:32.4554513Z Requirements to unlock own
2022-06-16T20:41:32.4554747Z Updating org.apache.poi:poi is not allowed
2022-06-16T20:41:32.4555148Z Checking if org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml 4.1.1 needs updating
2022-06-16T20:41:32.4555414Z Requirements to unlock own
2022-06-16T20:41:32.4555760Z Updating org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml is not allowed
```

Adding full yaml as requested

```
version: 2
updates:
- package-ecosystem: maven
  directory: "/xxx"
  target-branch: "xxx"
  open-pull-requests-limit: 10
  allow:
    - dependency-name: "org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml"
```

Comment: Please provide the full YAML plus the executed command with arguments. Because `allow` is not the only configuration that effects in not allowed updates.

Comment: Added full yaml to question as requested.

Answer (score 0):

The allow property of your configuration:

```
  allow:
    - dependency-name: "org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml"
```

Should lead to behavior as specified by the docs:

> Use the `allow` option to customize **which dependencies are updated**.
> Dependabot checks for all allowed dependencies and **then filters out** any `ignored` dependencies or versions. So a **dependency that is matched by both** an allow and an ignore **will be ignored**.
> [..]. You can use the following options:
>
> - `dependency-name` - use to allow updates for dependencies with **matching names**, optionally using `*` to match zero or more characters. For Java dependencies, the format of the `dependency-name` attribute is: `groupId:artifactId`, for example: `org.kohsuke:github-api`.

The first dependency of group `org.apache.poi` is not allowed, because your `allow` specified only the *artifact* `poi-ooxml`.

The second dependency should be allowed if not specified in `ignore`.

The logs indicate that there must be an overriding [`ignore`](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot/dependabot-version-updates/configuration-options-for-the-dependabot.yml-file#ignore) like explained in the docs:

> Dependencies can be ignored either by adding them to `ignore` or by using the `@dependabot ignore` command on a pull request opened by Dependabot.

Thus the logs state "not allowed":

```
2022-06-16T20:41:32.4554747Z Updating org.apache.poi:poi is not allowed
[..]
2022-06-16T20:41:32.4555760Z Updating org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml is not allowed
```

Comment: I added the yaml to my question, my yaml seems correct as per your comments. What can I do to be able to update poi-ooxml.